# jquery multiple droppables

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Basically creating a file manager. User clicks browse and a div populates with folders and files from the server and displayed as icons. I want to be able to drag files over folders and then run my server file move script. I got the file dragging working but when i move over a folder it picks up all the folders..

here is the folder code

```
$('.gallery_container').live("mouseover",function() {
    $(this).find("li.folder").each(function ( intIndex ){
        if (!$(this).data("init")) {
        $(this).data("init", true);
        $(this).droppable({
            accept: '.gallery li.file',
            activeClass: 'selected',
            drop: function(ev, ui) {
                droppedWorkout(ui.draggable,$(this));
            }
        });
    }

        });
    });
```

so when i drag over one folder all the folders get the selected class applied to it when it shouldn't?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `activeClass: 'selected'`, but you need `hoverClass: 'selected'`